# Display Exchange Calendar Using ASP.NET or SharePoint

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint, calendar, exchange-server

I would like to display an exchange calendar on our intranet using SharePoint or ASP.NET. It seems that it can be done using exchange web services, but to write it from scratch must involve reinventing wheels. Does anyone know of a simple way to display an exchange calendar without writing an application from scratch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No code solution:

- move the calendar from Exchange to SharePoint (so SP is now the primary source)
- let any user that needs access link it to their Exchange account

No exactly the answer to your question but it should get the same end result.

Answer (score 1):

with SharePoint you can link it at a webpart.  i.e. https://exchangeURL/Exchange/userid/Calendar/?Cmd=contents